# Is there a repository of Latex templates where I can find one good for visual-learning?

Tags: graphics, formatting, templates

I'm looking to create a set of VERY VERY NEAT looking notes, for long-term review. Would anyone happen to know of a template that is suitable for a more visual learner (the subject is still math)? Preferably one with color, and with boxes separating the concepts, and maybe even arrows/lines connecting boxes. Something almost like an infographic; I want to create bite-sized, condensed notes for math topics like probability, ODEs, stochastic processes, etc.

An alternative is to insert text boxes in Word, but I like the Latex font.

BTW that brings up a side note: if there is a template that draws state diagrams that would be great too (the little circles with arrows going to/from them, for stochastic processes). Line charts for calculus would be amazing too, but I feel like I'm asking for too much. I might just copy/paste for those.

EDIT: something like this, but plain skinny black lines for aesthetics.
https://www.r-bloggers.com/diy-cheat-sheets/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Your question is opinion based. Templates in the LaTeX world are something, most experienced users dislike very very *very* much.

Comment: This is a lot of question in one. For boxes in general `tcolorbox` is a great package (with an equally great documentation). It even appears to be possible to add arrows between such boxes (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/390962/35864). For most of your other graphing needs (Markov Chain diagrams, function plots) you'll probably want to look into Ti*k*Z and `pgfplots` or some higher-level packages based on them. You'll find lots of questions about those things on this site.