# Align the TikZ Arrows to the Center

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I got something like a simple flow chart that is shown below in the screenshot.
But, I would like to vertically shift the arrows so that they are in the middle, instead of be on the top of the row.

[image]

The code I use is copied below.
Can anyone let me know what should be changed in order to shift the arrows down to the middle? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[table, 11pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows}

\tikzset{
  arrow/.style={draw,thick,->,>=stealth},
}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
boxsep=-1pt, left=-2pt, right=-2pt,
boxrule=0.5pt,
colframe=black, colback=white, sharp corners
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=25pt,
  every edge/.style={arrow}
  ]
\node[text width=0.25\textwidth] (A) {
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title={},coltitle=black,attach title to upper={},enhanced jigsaw]
    \centering
    Some text
    \end{tcolorbox}
};
\node[text width=0.25\textwidth] (B) [right=of A.east] {
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=\parbox{\textwidth}{},coltitle=black,attach title to upper={},enhanced jigsaw]
    \centering
    Some text
    \end{tcolorbox}
};
\node[text width=0.25\textwidth] (C) [right=of B.east] {
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=\parbox{\textwidth}{},coltitle=black,attach title to upper={},enhanced jigsaw]
    \centering
    Some text
    \end{tcolorbox}
};

\draw[arrow] (A) -- (B);
\draw[arrow] (B) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have the feeling that nesting `tcolorbox`es inside `\node`s is not a good idea. Could you explain why this is needed? Why don't you use simple `\node`s? If you really need to use `tcolorbox`es, it is probably better to place them first and then use an overlay to draw the arrows.

Comment: If you nest a `tcolorbox` inside a `\node`, you are essentially nesting two `tikzpictures` which should be avoided, because this is not supported and can lead to strange results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may consider the following simple MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 25pt,
  start chain = going right,
   arr/.style = {-Straight Barb, thick, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt},
     N/.style = {draw, thick, minimum width=0.25*\linewidth,
              on chain, join=by arr}
                    ]
\node (A) [N]   {Some text};
\node (B) [N]   {Some text};
\node (B) [N]   {Some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

- As you can see, in MWE are employed `chains` library for positioning oh nodes, for nodes are defined common style `N`, arrows between them are drawn by macro `join`.
- I don't see any reason to use `tcolorbox` (at least this is not evident from your question).

**Addendum  1:**
if you like to have nodes with title, you can do this by use of `shapes.multipart` library. In the following MWE is shown "emulation" of the `tcolorbox` by using it:

```
\documentclass[11pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                shadows, shapes.multipart}
% for emulation tcolorbox with title
% unfortunately it is still not part of shapes.multipart library :-(
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@extra@preaction#1{% hackery which enable preactions
                            % in multi-part node on a different layer
                            % suggested by Mark Wibrow on c.t.t. (2010)
  {%
    \pgfsys@beginscope%
      \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\voidb@x%
      \begingroup\tikzset{#1}\expandafter\endgroup%
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@preaction@layer
\expandafter{\tikz@preaction@layer}%
      \ifx\tikz@preaction@layer\pgfutil@empty%
      \path[#1];% do extra path
      \else%
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{\tikz@preaction@layer}%
      \path[#1];%
      \end{pgfonlayer}
      \fi%
      \pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath\tikz@actions@path% restore
      \tikz@restorepathsize%
    \pgfsys@endscope%
  }%
}
\let\tikz@preaction@layer=\pgfutil@empty
\tikzset{preaction layer/.store in=\tikz@preaction@layer}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]  % <--- needed for style definition with #
\frametitle{test with of the Ti*k*Z library \texttt{shapes.multipart}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 25pt,
      start chain = going right,
       arr/.style = {-Straight Barb, thick, shorten <=4pt, shorten >=2pt},
 mpnv/.style args = {#1/#2}{% multi part node horisontal % <---
        rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split part fill={blue!70!black, white},
        preaction layer=background,       % <-- prepare layer for drop shadow
        drop shadow,
        text width = 0.25*\linewidth, align=center,
        draw, thick, rounded corners,
        node contents = {\nodepart[font=\bfseries, text=yellow]{one}  #1  % for title
                         \nodepart[align=left]{two}  #2},  % for main text
        on chain, join=by arr
                            }
                    ]
\node (A) [mpnv=title/some longer text in wo lines];
\node (B) [mpnv=title/some short text];
\node (B) [mpnv=title/some text];
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum 2:**
If you more prefer to use of the `tcolorbox`ses, than try solution proposed in answer [add-arrow-between-two-tcolorboxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390963), to which your question is actually duplicate. Adopting it to your case, the MWE can be:

```
\documentclass[11pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}
\tcbset{%
    boxrule=2pt,
    colback=white, % background color
    colframe=cyan, % frame colour
        halign=left,
        valign=center,
    sharp corners=all,
    center title,
    lower separated=false,
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
    adjusted title=center,
    width=0.25\linewidth % added
    }


    \begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test with \texttt{tcolorbox}}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 25pt,
  start chain = going right,
   arr/.style = {draw=cyan, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, line width=2pt, 
                 shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt},
     N/.style = {on chain, join=by arr}
                    ]
    \node(A) [N] {
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title= Title 1]
        some longer text in three lines
        \end{tcolorbox}
    };
\node(B) [N] {  % added position of second box
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=Title 2]
       some short text
        \end{tcolorbox}
        };
\node(C) [N] {  % added position of second box
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=Title 3]
       some text
        \end{tcolorbox}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The `tcolorbox` is there because in some use cases I have something like a titled box there. That's why I put `tcolorbox` in the code. If `tcolorbox` makes things over complicated, I could try to avoid that.

Comment: @Norman, in such a cases is better to use `shapes.multipart` library (see package documentation, paragraph *rectangle split`, pp 819).

Comment: @Norman, see both addendums. It seems that you looking for solution in the second one :-)