# How to add headers to nodes in a TikZ flowchart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, flow-charts

I would like to create a flowchart in LaTeX with this basic design:

[image]

I have tried following the [Creating Flowcharts](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ%3A_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_3)%E2%80%94Creating_Flowcharts) tutorial from Overleaf, but I couldn't find out how to add the titles to the boxes.

What I currently have is the following code:

```
\tikzstyle{box} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=2cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=black!15]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [very thick, ->, >=stealth]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
    \node (box1) [box] {text};
    \node (box2) [box, below of=box1] {more text};
    \draw [arrow] (box1) -- (box2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This produces the following flowchart:

[image]

Now I would just like to add the titles to the boxes, as in the first image.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful if you could edit into your question your current code and what it looks like, it is fine if it doesn't work or have what you want that's what this question is for, but questions like this that don't show you have wrote any code are not how this site works. Could you edit into your question some code that you have wrote please?

Comment: @JamesT I just updated the question.

Comment: Define `\tikzset{header/.style={label={[rectangle, fill=white, draw, anchor=center, name=\tikzlastnode-header]north:{#1}}}}` in the preamble and then `\node (box2) [box, below of=box1, header=Title2] {more text}; \draw[arrow] (box1) -- (box2-header);` for example.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you @Qrrbrbirlbel !

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, please extend your comment to an answer, please.

Comment: You can use `tcolorbox` package, similarly as is done in in the second addendum in the https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/690603/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a job for a [`label`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.10.2) which is just another node added afterwards which is placed in relation to the main node.

Depending on your usage, you might want to use something more automatic that automatically chooses whether `<name>` or `<name>-header` will be used for the arrows.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}
\tikzset{
  box/.style = {
    rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=2cm,
    text centered, draw=gray, fill=black!15},
  arrow/.style={very thick, -Stealth},
  header/.style={
    label={[rectangle, fill=white, draw, anchor=center,
            minimum width=2cm, node font=\ttfamily,
            name=\tikzlastnode-header]north:{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (box1) [box, header = Title1]                {text};
\node (box2) [box, header = Title2, below=of box1] {more text};
\draw [arrow] (box1) -- (box2-header);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]